# Prove A can be written as the sum of such matrices

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Let $A$ be a matrix whose entries are either 1 or 0.The number of entries which equals 1 for every row of $A$ is exactly $k$ and the number of 1 for every column is no larger than $k$.Prove that there exists $P_1,P_2,\cdots,P_k$,such that $A=\sum\limits_{i=1}^kP_i$,and for each $P_i$,the number of 1 for every row is 1,the number of 1 for every column is no larger than 1.

Ideas:This can also be seen as a matching problem in graph theory.If we take every row (X) and every column (Y) as a vertex,and they are connected iff the entry is 1.This is a bigragh.If we induct on k,for $k'\leq k-1$ it holds,then for $A$,we need to find the $P_k$,such that $A-P_k$ is fit for the induction.For all the vertex $Y'$ in $Y$ whose degree equals $k$,then we need a match between $X$ and $Y$,such that every $X$ and every $Y'$ is matched.

Comment: Are you familiar with Hall's Marriage Theorem? If not, look it up, as it's really neat and it will settle your question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson From Hall's Marriage Theorem,there is a match between Y' and a subset of X(say X'),then how to prove there is a match between X-X' and Y-Y'?

Comment: Every collection of $r$ rows has $rk$ ones, so there are at least $r$ columns that have a one in common with one of those rows. By Hall, you can match each row to a different column such that the slot determined by the row and column has a one. There's your $P_1$. Subtract it off and repeat.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Maybe I misunderstand what you mean.After the subtraction,every row has k-1 ones,but how to guarantee that every column has $\leq$ k-1 ones?

Comment: I see your point. I'll have to think about it. Maybe it helps to first expand the matrix to a square matrix with each row and each column having exactly $k$ ones.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer that I posted yesterday?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I saw it just now and I will think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any such matrix has at least as many columns as rows (by counting the total number of ones in two different ways; by rows, and by columns). If it is a square matrix, then (by the same technique) every column has exactly $k$ ones. If it is not a square matrix, it can be extended to one by adjoining enough rows to make it square, putting $k$ ones in the rows you have added, putting those ones where they can go without causing any column to overflow (that is, to have more than $k$ ones). So, either way, we get a square matrix $B$ of zeros and ones, with exactly $k$ ones in each row and in each column.

Now we can apply Hall's Theorem to find a permutation matrix $P_1$ such that $P_1$ has ones only in places where $B$ has ones. Then $B-P_1$ is a square matrix of zeros and ones with exactly $k-1$ ones in each row and in each column. Iterate the procedure $k$ times to get $B=\sum_1^kP_i$. Then delete the additional rows from $B$ and from each $P_i$ to get $A=\sum_1^kP'_i$ where each $P'_i$ has a single one in each row, and at most one one in each column.

Comment: Why can we manage to add the rows without causing any column to overflow?

Comment: OK, I see the problem. If we start with, say, $\pmatrix{1&1&0\cr1&1&0\cr}$, then we must go to $\pmatrix{1&1&0\cr1&1&0\cr0&0&2\cr}$; we have to use entries larger than one. Nevertheless, we wind up with a square matrix with positive integer entries, with every row and every column having the same sum, and we can still subtract off permutation matrices to express our augmented matrix as a sum of permutation matrices.

Comment: Still one problem:if we set that the matrix can have entries larger than 1,then the two vertices are connected iff the entry is not  0.But now the degree of the new added row may be less than $k$,so does the Hall's Theorem still hold?

Comment: Always make the new row have numbers adding up to $k$. Any $r$ rows have numbers adding up to $rk$, no column has numbers adding uo to more than $k$, so it takes $r$ columns (at least) to cover the $r$ rows, and Hall applies.

Comment: OK,I think the answer is right.Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank you for keeping me honest!